# Replace HTML tags using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Here is my code

```
String html = "<font>fsdfs<font>dfsdf</font>dasdasd</font>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("font");
for(Element element : elements)
{
element.replaceWith(new Element(Tag.valueOf("span"),"").html(element.html()));
}


System.out.println(doc.html());
```

I want to replace font tag and put span tag. In this it will replace first font tag but not second tag

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can replace the Tag like this too:

```
String html = "<font>fsdfs<font>dfsdf</font>dasdasd</font>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("font");


// rename all 'font'-tags to 'span'-tags, will also keep attributs etc.
elements.tagName("span");

System.out.println(doc.html());
```