# Jsoup - How to create my own tags with self closing

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to extract certain tags from a html document. But, I need to change some of them with some tags created by the team.

Example

```
<inline id="inline-1" />  --->  <abc:123 input="1"/>
```

Check that my tag requires the self closing tag. Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Element(Jsoup.parse(<(yourtagnamehere) />).body().child(0).tag(),"").html(el.html());` to create a tag that is **self closing** and contains the html of the tag to be replaced. Notice the `< />` is required to ensure the tag is self closing. You can then use the aforementioned element to replace the required tags(`element.replaceWith()`) and set the attributes using `getElementsByTagName` and `.attr()`.

### Demonstration code:

```java
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Attributes;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Attribute;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.EscapeMode;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*; 
import org.jsoup.parser.Tag;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String body = "<inline id=\"inline-1\" />";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(body);
    System.out.println("Original:\n"+doc.html()+"\n");
    System.out.println("Replaced:\n"+replaceTagWithCustom(doc, "inline", "<abc:123 />").html());
    //You can then add attribute as you want
    doc.getElementsByTag("abc:123").first().attr("input", "1");
    System.out.println("\nReplaced with attributes:\n"+doc.html());
}

    static Document replaceTagWithCustom(Document doc, String original, String replacement){
        //Can be changed to select to get multiple elements
        Element el = doc.selectFirst(original); 
        //Change tagname while conserving self closing(Note: requires format <(yourtag) /> to add self closing)
        Element el2 = new Element(Jsoup.parse(replacement).body().child(0).tag(),"").html(el.html());
        //Strip all attributes
        List<String>  attToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
        Attributes at = el.attributes();
        for (Attribute a : at) {
            attToRemove.add(a.getKey());
        }
        for(String att : attToRemove) {
            el.removeAttr(att);
        }
        el.replaceWith(el2);
        return doc;
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
Original:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <inline id="inline-1" />
 </body>
</html>

Replaced:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <abc:123 />
 </body>
</html>

Replaced with attributes:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <abc:123 input="1" />
 </body>
</html>
```

References:
[Allow configuration of self closing for tags](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/502) - Legioth
[SO: Replace tags with Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475213/replace-html-tags-using-jsoup#:%7E:text=You%20can%20replace%20the%20Tag%20like%20this%20too%3A,keep%20attributs%20etc.%20elements.tagName%20%28%22span%22%29%3B%20System.out.println%20%28doc.html%20%28%29%29%3B) - Hardik Lotiya
[SO: Remove attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233938/jsoup-attribute-removal-on-html-tags) - Xtroce
[Jsoup: modifying attributes](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-attributes)